# Converting Spring XML to JavaConfig with Variable and Resource Import

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, resources, spring-java-config

I have a spring boot application where I am trying to convert the following spring xml config to java config:

```
<bean id="pageDAO" factory-bean="springWSDaoFactory"
    factory-method="createPageDAO" lazy-init="true">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${cds.host}" />
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Integer" value="${cds.port}" />
</bean>

<!-- CoreApi + plugins configuration    -->             
<import resource="classpath:coreAPI_SpringWSContext.xml"/>      
<bean name="springWSDaoFactory" class="com.blan.torque.dao.springws.SpringWSDAOFactory" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="serviceVersion" value="${service.version}"/>
    <property name="securityKey" value="${service.key}"/>
</bean>
```

Here's what I have for javaconfig so far:

```
@Bean
public PageDAO pageDAO() {
    return springWSDAOFactory().createPageDAO(null, null);
}

@Bean
public SpringWSDAOFactory springWSDAOFactory() {
    SpringWSDAOFactory springWSDAOFactory = new SpringWSDAOFactory();
    springWSDAOFactory.setServiceVersion(null);
    springWSDAOFactory.setSecurityKey(null);
    return springWSDAOFactory;
}
```

I have no idea how to implement `<import resource...../>` in Java let alone import the variables like `${cds.host}`. I've put `null` everywhere as place holders. But any ideas on how to do this with annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration class you can use the annotation `@ImportResource` instead of `<import resource... />`.

To read Strings from a property file, try to declare an String using `@Value` and the use the previously declared string.

For example:

```
@Value("${service.version}")
private String serviceVersion;
```

Then using it as parameter

```
springWSDAOFactory.setServiceVersion(this.serviceVersion);
```

I hope have helped you.

Comment: this is what i wanted, perfect. Thanks!